# How to teach linear programming and reductions?

Tags: undergraduate-education, textbooks, teaching

Do you know any textbook with problems+solutions to support teaching of linear programming and reductions, and in particular, cover standard and slack forms, formulation of problems as linear programs, simplex method and algorithm, duality, etc.?

Comment: Could you improve your question by adding context, such as, are students primarily math majors, or comp sci majors, or both?  What pre-requisites exist for the class you plan to teach? Have you ever taught such a class, and if so, what text did you use? Or are you a student wanting to self-study, and if so, what courses have you taken?  One-sentence questions are usually inappropriate and/or insufficient and/or unclear so as to yield helpful answers.

Answer (score 6):

This does not directly address your question (and so is not an answer). But I consult this textbook when touching upon
linear programming when teaching Algorithms, and I find it
an impressive, unusually concise (~200 pages) text.

> [Matousek, Jiri, and Bernd Gärtner. Understanding and using linear programming. *Springer Science & Business Media,* 2007.](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540306979?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIyqvji4Sk5gIVUPDACh07xgrZEAQYASABEgLLmfD_BwE).

"The book is an introductory textbook mainly for students of computer science and mathematics."

---

[image]

          

<sup>The Klee-Minty cube (p.76).</sup>

---

I especially appreciate the authors connecting the linear
algebra to geometry.

Comment: Can you offer a little more with respect why you promote this text, and not others, and your experience with the text?  Otherwise, it strikes me as only a "link only answer" found by Google.

Comment: You're right, "This does not directly address" the OP's question, and would best be replaced by a comment below the answer.  Did you merely Google this text and read a review? Or rather, have you *used this text when teaching*, and hence, consider the text *an impressive textbook, unusually concise."  If the latter is true, please state so in your answer, and then please share with us why you think the text is "impressive."  I could Google and "turn up" many such texts, and call them "impressive," etc., but that's not the same as sharing one's personal experience using the text.

Answer (score 2):

A simple Google search (linear programming problems and solutions textbook) yields this result as the first hit:

https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540417446 (Linear Optimization and Extensions:
Problems and Solutions; Authors: Alevras, Dimitris, Padberg, Manfred W.)

This appears to be exactly what you are looking for, based on reading the intro as well as just the title itself.  An alternate approach is to use the first six chapters of the Schaum's Outline on Operations Research (looking at the table of contents, viewable on line using the "see inside" feature at Amazon, shows they cover your topics).

The Google search also shows that this question has been asked several times on the main (non-ed) math site.  Several other texts have been suggested.  Worth a look, although you will find many people who just suggest the text they had or who ignore the problems/solutions characteristic, a requirement for you.  Still, worth a quick look if the two previous solutions are not what you want.

Comment: This should have been a comment: "Do a Google search".  Your answer is a link-only answer, in that sense, aka LMGTFY (Let me Google that for you) answer.